# Where should I ask a question about what language a text is in?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a text (below if anybody recognizes it), and I don't know what language it’s in. I've spent hours upon hours trying to figure it out, using [Omniglot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omniglot) and the like. I've got nothing. I went on the linguistics Stack Exchange site, and got my question closed with zero answers. Do you know where the best place to ask such a question would be?

[image]

Comment: Its possible its not a real language. What's the source?

Comment: @W.O. He [already did](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/45351/what-language-is-this-is-there-a-translation)... [twice](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/45357/how-does-one-decode-a-language).

Comment: Best I can suggest is [omniglot](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/sunuwar.htm), nowhere on the network then. ;)

Comment: @W.O omniglot didn't work.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I got it at a pawn shop. I did a statistical analysis of a few pages and it seems to follow Zipfs law of distribution.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I did. The first was closed, and the second was asking how to do it myself (which seems to be impossible for anybody who isn't an expert).